# should sub items inherit the permission of parent folder?

Tags: linux

for example, i want to write and remove the file `/var/temp/1.txt`. Then what permission should i give to `1.txt` file and its parent folder?

In my opinion, if the parent folder is unexecutable or unwritable(655 or 555), then the sub items are unwritable and undeletable, right?

In other words,

1. which permission of `/var/temp` determine that `/var/temp/1.txt` is writable/unwritable, and
2. which permission of `/var/temp` determine that `/var/temp/1.txt` is deletable/Undeletable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executable permissions on a directory allow users to cd into that directory and list files.
If write permission does not exist on that directory then none of the files within the directory can be removed or changed.
Executable permissions on a file allow that file to be executed. It is write permissions on a file that dictate whether it can be changed or deleted.

In conclusion, to change a file within a directory, the file would need write permission and the directory would need write and execute permissions.